# Build Fails When Done Through Cloud Build Pipeline But works if run through CMD

Tags: pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Cloud Build Pipeline (GCP) fails when pandas and big-Query is Used.But Works OK when done through CMD
gcloud run deploy.
It says Pyarrow Build failed.And also struck at following.
Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running..."
timestamp: "2023-10-20T12:34:31.424314594Z"

Tried to deploy it on GCP But Got Above error.

````
# [END cloudbuild_python_yaml]
# Copyright 2020 Google LLC
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# [START cloudbuild_python_yaml]
# [START cloudbuild_python_dependencies_yaml]
steps:
  # Install dependencies
  - name: python
    entrypoint: pip
    args: ["install","-r", "requirements.txt", "--user"]
  # [END cloudbuild_python_dependencies_yaml]
  # [START cloudbuild_python_image_yaml]
  # [START cloudbuild_python_deploy_yaml]
  # Deploy to Cloud Run
  - name: google/cloud-sdk
    args:
      [
   "gcloud","builds" ,"submit", "--tag", "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/flask_${SHORT_SHA}"
      ]
  - name: google/cloud-sdk
    args:
      [
        "gcloud",
        "run",
        "deploy",
        "backend",
        "--image",
        "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/flask_${SHORT_SHA}",
        "--region",
        "us-central1",
        "--platform",
        "managed",
        "--allow-unauthenticated",
      ]
  
  # [END cloudbuild_python_deploy_yaml]
substitutions:
  _IMAGE: my-image-name
images: [$_IMAGE:$COMMIT_SHA]
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY```
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.